# Find all paths between airports with price less than 3000 in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database where Airports are connected with each other by Flights using relations :ORIGIN and :DESTINATION. To each flight there's a ticket connected by relation :ASSIGN. The price is saved on a ticket.

Now I need to find all paths starting in Airport LAX, but with price less than 3000.
I was able to find all paths, but I don't know how to connect a tickets to it.

My query for finding paths:

```
MATCH (origin:Airport { name:"LAX" }),(destination:Airport)
WITH origin,destination
MATCH path = (origin)-[r*..5]-(destination)
RETURN path
```

One path that is returned from that query:

> [{"name":"LAX"},{},{"date":"11/29/2015 15:18:22","duration":269,"dista
>   nce":2611,"airline":"19977"},{"date":"11/29/2015 15:18:22","duration":
>   269,"distance":2611,"airline":"19977"},{},{"name":"BOS"},{"name":"BOS"
>   },{},{"date":"11/29/2015 01:20:17","duration":289,"distance":2704,"air
>   line":"19977"},{"date":"11/29/2015 01:20:17","duration":289,"distance"
>   :2704,"airline":"19977"},{},{"name":"SFO"}]

How to assign ticket to it and make a where to have only those with price less than 3000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this query to produce sample data:

```
CREATE (origin:Airport { name:"LAX" })<-[:ORIGIN]-(f1:Flight {date:"11/29/2015 15:18:22",duration:269,distance:2611,airline:"19977"})-[:DESTINATION]->(d1:Airport {name:"BOS"})<-[:ORIGIN]-(f2:Flight {date:"11/29/2015 01:20:17",duration:289,distance :2704,airline:"19977"})-[:DESTINATION]->(d2:Airport {name:"SFO"}),
(t:Ticket {id: 1, price: 1234})-[:ASSIGN]->(f1),
(t1:Ticket {id: 2, price: 555})-[:ASSIGN]->(f2)
```

this query should produce all paths up to length 5 in which each leg's price is less than 3000:

```
MATCH path = (origin:Airport { name:"LAX" })<-[r:ORIGIN|DESTINATION*..5]->(destination:Airport)
WHERE ALL(f IN [n IN NODES(path) WHERE 'Flight' IN LABELS(n)]
  WHERE [(f)<-[:ASSIGN]-(ticket) | ticket.price < 3000][0])
RETURN path
```

The results will contain 2 paths. If you changed the price of `t1` to 3000, then the results will only contain 1 path (the shorter one).

[UPDATE]

If you only want paths where the total ticket price is less than 3000, then this would work:

```
MATCH path = (origin:Airport { name:"LAX" })<-[r:ORIGIN|DESTINATION*..5]->(destination:Airport)
WHERE REDUCE(s = 0, n IN [x IN NODES(path) WHERE 'Flight' IN LABELS(x)] |
  s + [(n)<-[:ASSIGN]-(ticket) | ticket.price][0]
  ) < 3000
RETURN path
```

Comment: Your answer works great, but I made a mistake in description as I need to find sum of tickets less than 3000 for a path instead of each ticket having price lower than 3000

Comment: In that solution LAX is always a ORIGIN?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Why is there [0]? I'm asking because when I put 1 or 2 there it works but the prices returned are different. So is that taking the price from the first ticket type?

Comment: The question stated that "To each flight there's a ticket connected by relation :ASSIGN", which implies each flight has a single ticket. That is also what my answer's sample data has. So, the `[0]` is just getting the one and only ticket for each flight. If your data has some other situation, then you need to adjust the Cypher accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @cybersam . In my case there are three types of tickets so as far as I know the query gets much more complicated.